# Conditional formula in excel for range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, worksheet-function

I am working on getting together an easy way for our sales force to keep up with their time, sales and proposals.
In cell B2:B20 they list the names of the people that have made contact with, in cells c2:c20 they list whether that person was a contact (c), lead (l), Proposal (P) or sale (S).
I have been trying to figure out a formula so that if in cells c2:c20, they have "P" listed, that it will list the contacts name from the corresponding B cell in a table on the page.

Comment: So if cell B2 is "John Doe" and cell C2 is a "P", then you want to show "John Doe" in some other table? Does that table have a cell for each of the people? And for those that don't have a "P", you want it blank?

Comment: `=IF(C2="P",B2,"")` something like that?

Comment: Doing it the way you showed works, but then we would have to have a cell in the table for each cell that could potentially have a "P". We are trying to get away from that. Out of all those contacts, only 2 or 3 will be assigned a "P" value so we have a table with just a few spots on it. I am hoping for a way that if it does not have a "p" value then it just looks through the next cell, and then just enters the information once it runs into a "p"

Comment: The target table would have to be dynamic, since perhaps nobody has a P, or most or all could have a P in that column. Is there other information in the target table? If not, perhaps a better way to look at just the "P" rows is to use the auto-filter (`Sort & Filter > Filter`)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to list those names in F2 down - try this "array formula" in `F2` confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(C$2:C$20="P",ROW(C$2:C$20)),ROWS(F$2:F2))),"")`

When you run out of names you'll get blanks

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. Put the formula in cell 1. Select cell with formula then press `F2` key to select formula - now hold  down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` keys while pressing `ENTER` - if you do that correctly then curly braces like { and } appear around the formula - now copy formula down column